# How to create "full page dialog" with DurandalJS

Tags: durandal

I'm trying to eliminate "css modal windows" (modal windows are not mobile device best friends) of a web client side application (SPA), built with DurandalJS version 2.

I would like to convert the modal windows to full page dialogs. It would still be a dialog window but instead of superimpose the div over the current view, I would like to hide the current view (while keeping its state) and show the div containing the dialog (using the "entrance" transition if possible or a similar technique - to keep a consistent flow).

I think I am close to a solution. The two options I'm trying at the moment are using the dialog plugin as is (by adding a new dialog context) or creating a new plugin based on the dialog plugin. Either way, I am stock at the point where I need to hide the current view.

Any ideas how to go with this or how to determine the current active view from the compositionComplete hook inside a dialog context?

Related question on the [DurandalJS Google Groups](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/durandaljs/-qJQSSmNtao)

**Edit 1** (following @CodingGorilla comments)

Using the entrance transition as is, is not the important part here. I could live with copying the code of the transition. But what is paramount, is that I should not navigate to a new view. The concept is exactly the same as a dialog in DurandalJS. The only difference is the presentation. A dialog should *not* have a URL, it is contextual to the current state/window.

Comment: Do you want to hide the current view (ie. change the `div` style to `display: none` and the compose in the new view?  If the new view is the "full page" then what's the point in hiding the other view since the new dialog view is going to sit on top of everything?

Comment: No. Same as the dialog plugin does. The dialog plugin creates a new environment (composition/activator/host/div) for the dialog. I don't want to lose the current view. I just want to hide it while the dialog is displayed. Also, I want to be able to stack the dialogs as the dialog plugin currently does.

Comment: So what specifically are you stuck on?  All you really should have to do is change the CSS on the dialog to make it width and height 100%.

Comment: As I said, I would like to keep a consistent navigation and use the entrance transition to hide the current view and show the dialog but I need to be able to pass the current view object to the entrance transition and I don't know how to get this object from the compositionComplete callback.

Comment: You can't use the transition in that way; the transitions are meant to be called between views, when one view is being removed from the DOM and another view is being composed into the DOM.  In this case, you're not doing that, you're just hiding the containing element and putting a new one in.  What you would need to do is make your dialogs a new view and add a route to that view and then do the appropriate navigation.

Comment: @CodingGorilla Sorry but I don't agree with you. I have tried what you propose already and I'm sure there's a way to do what I want, the way I see it now. The transition code is really simple, the dialog plugin already use a new composition. I don't want to navigate away from the current view. I will continue to investigate and I'll post my findings here. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I got it. It is not as pretty as I would like it to be but I am very happy to be able to reuse the dialog plugin and the transition mechanism as is.

Here is the dialog context that I use:

```
define(['jquery', 'knockout', 'transitions/entrance', 'plugins/dialog'], function ($, ko, entrance, dialog) {
    return {
        addHost: function (theDialog) {
            //Cheat - only applies to my project (where I want to put the dialog - side-by-side with the current active view)
            var container = $('div.document-edit');

            var host = $('<div></div>').appendTo(body);
            theDialog.host = host.get(0);

            //Cheat - the view I want to hide (while the dialog is displayed)
            theDialog.activeView = container.find("div[data-active-view='true']:first").get(0); 
        },
        removeHost: function (theDialog) {
            var context = {
                activeView: theDialog.host,
                child: theDialog.activeView,
                triggerAttach: function () { } //Cheat - no need for triggerAttach
            };

            entrance(context).then(function () {
                ko.removeNode(theDialog.host);
            });
        },
        compositionComplete: function (child, parent, context) {
            var theDialog = dialog.getDialog(context.model);
            context.activeView = theDialog.activeView;

            //Cheat - no need for triggerAttach
            context.triggerAttach = function () { }; 

            entrance(context).then(function () { });
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: Where do you add this code? I am trying to do the same thing using TypeScript but I have no idea where this code should be placed!

Comment: @NormandBedard This code is a "dialog context". If you take a look at the end of the file of the dialog plugin you will see how the default one is added. Next, you can add your own in the main module, when the application starts, like this: dialog.addContext('fullPageDialog', fullPageDialogContext);

Comment: Watch out for the back button tough. I had to to some more steps to handle the back button so it closes the dialog (since I'm creating "full page" dialogs) instead of navigating away.